# Как вывести массив в консоль Java?

Tags: java, массивы

Вместо вывода самого массива в консоль, у меня выводится вот такое сообщение:

```
[[I@1b6d3586  
[[I@1b6d3586
```

Сам код:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] matrix1 = new int[2][2];
        matrix1[0][0] = 5;
        matrix1[1][0] = 1;
        matrix1[0][1] = 4;
        matrix1[1][1] = 0;

        for(int[] a : matrix1){
            System.out.println(matrix1);
        }
    }
}
```

Как это дело исправить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возможно, вам даже не нужен цикл для вывода массива на экран:

```
Arrays.deepToString(matrix1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
for(int[] a : matrix1)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Comment: Отлично! toString выручает)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с использованием `stream` для двухмерного массива:

```
Arrays.stream(matrix).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Он долгий. Намного дольше, чем циклом.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия почему вы так думаете?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я вчера проверял.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия как замеряли?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev `long l = System.nanoTime();` `System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - l);`. И сейчас проверил. Цикл 294600, стрим 1913200.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия посмотрите этот доклад - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pMfUopQ9Es

Comment: @ИмяФамилия вам правильную ссылку дали, `System.nanoTime()` - очень грубый способ замера. Я только что прогнал под [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) код из этого ответа и из вашего. Разница в среднем времени выполнения отличается на 0.4 миллисекунды. Что ожидаемо, так как у обоих вариантов примерно одинаковое количество аллокаций и вызовов.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev всё-таки непонятно, откуда такая большая разница: 294600 и 1913200. И 400 микросекунд - это много.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ возможно ваша JVM в этот момент занималась чем-нибудь другим. А 400 микросекунд это не так уж много. если учесть, что сборщик мусора работал по 19 миллисекунд в процессе выполнения обоих бенчмарков. Сборка мусора занимает в 47 раз больше времени, чем разница в среднем выполнении между тестами!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я сделал с `Thread.sleep(100)`. Результат тот же. Кажется, это ни на что не влияет.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия таки посмотрите видео.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev посмотрел, но конкретно в этом случае ничего критичного не вижу.